# Replace multiple NA columns iteratively in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a R tibble `df`.

```
df

id        gender        age
1         M             young
1         M             middle
1         M             old
1         F             young
1         F             middle
1         F             old
2         M             young
...
4         NA            NA
5         NA            NA
6         M             young
...
```

For each `id`, `gender` consists of `M`, `F`, and `age` consists of `young`, `middle`, `old`. In other words, each `id` should have six different entries. There are some `id`s with `NA`s in both subsequent columns.

My goal is to fill all the `NA`s in `gender` and `age` into the aforementioned 6 combinations.

For example, `id == 4` and `id == 5` currently have each one row of `NA`s, but I would like to have both `id`s to have 6 rows of each `gender` and `age` combinations, similarly to `id == 1`.

---

I am familiar with `tidyr::crossing` that does the iteration, and also with `mutate_at(..., ~ replace_na)`, but applying either of them in my pipe does not return my desired outcome.

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `complete` with `nesting` and remove the rows with NA like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  complete(id, nesting(gender, age)) %>%
  drop_na(gender, age)
#> # A tibble: 30 × 3
#>       id gender age   
#>    <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1     1 F      middle
#>  2     1 F      old   
#>  3     1 F      young 
#>  4     1 M      middle
#>  5     1 M      old   
#>  6     1 M      young 
#>  7     2 F      middle
#>  8     2 F      old   
#>  9     2 F      young 
#> 10     2 M      middle
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used**:

```
df = read.table(text = 'id        gender        age
1         M             young
1         M             middle
1         M             old
1         F             young
1         F             middle
1         F             old
2         M             young
4         NA            NA
5         NA            NA
6         M             young', header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with base R functions, you can do the following:

Pretend this is your data:

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6),
           gender=c("M","M","M","F","F","F","M","M",NA,NA,"M"),
           age=c("young","middle","old","young","young",NA,NA,"young","young","young","young"))
```

You can use `expand.grid()` and `unique()` to come up with all combinations.

```
df2<-expand.grid(id=unique(df$id),gender=unique(df$gender),age=unique(df$age))
```

Next, for cleanup and removal of the NA values, you can use:

```
df3<-df2[!rowSums(is.na(df2[-1])),]
```

Now df3 has what you're looking for!